# PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import - Issue with import pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I have issue in importing pdf. Below is the error

> at PdfSharp.Internal.ParserDiagnostics.ThrowParserException(String message)   at PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.Parser.ReadXRefTableAndTrailer(PdfCrossReferenceTable xrefTable)   at PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.Parser.ReadTrailer()   at PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(Stream stream, String password, PdfDocumentOpenMode openmode, PdfPasswordProvider passwordProvider)   at PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(Stream stream, PdfDocumentOpenMode openmode)   at DAL.Helper.CreatePdfDocument.CreateEsignDoc(String sHTML, Byte[] doc, EsignInfo docInfo)

My code is as below

```
PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfFile = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(new MemoryStream(doc), PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pdf file might be corrupted. Open file in Adobe Reader & save again. 
You can find more details [here](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/issues/40)